# Multer react + node js unable to get req.file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

Hi I am trying to upload a file from fronend to backend using multer

**Front End**

```
var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("files", image[0]);
 formData.append("data", JSON.stringify({status: 'ACK', message: "You are fu*ked"});
return http.axios
  .post(apiUrl + apiDomain + "/createAnnouncement", formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  })
  .then((res) => res);
```

**Backend**

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Express = require("express");
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, config.get("announcemnt_upload_file_storage"));
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, file.filename + "_" + Date.now());
   },
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
const Router = Express.Router();
Router.route("/createAnnouncement").post(
   upload.single("files"),
  (req , resp, next) => {
console.log(" >>>>>>>", req.file);//THis returns undefined
console.log(">>>>", req.files);//This returns undefined
resp.send("Siccess")
 }
);
```

**Below is my Req snapshot**
[image: Req Snapshot]

Its not getting uploaded to storage and its returning undefined when called `req.file`

But if I try to see `req.body` I could see `[Object File] in console`

PLease suggest where I am going wrong

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65862484/how-to-upload-multiple-images-at-a-time-in-s3-bucket-using-node-js-express/65863294#65863294) here is an example of uploading multiple images with multer, try maybe, router.post("/",  upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
 const {file} = req;
 console.log(file); res.send("saved");
}

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help `https://github.com/RUSHI-GADHIYA/uploading-and-updating-image` see this